# glMultiDrawElements with GL_TRIANGLES - usage

Tags: opengl

In my OpenGL projects I have always used `glDrawElements` or `glDrawElementsBaseVertex` with `GL_TRIANGLES`. When rendering a complex object I can, for example sort meshes based on the material index, update textures and uniforms and call `glDrawElements` for each group.

I have started exploring other draw commands. I wonder when `glMuliDrawElements` is useful. I have found the following [example](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/MathCG2/OpenGLsoft/BasicDrawModes/explainBDM.html). There `glMulitDrawElements` is used with `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` and is in fact a equivalent for primitive restart functionality. That is clear.

When `glMuliDrawElements/glMultiDrawArrays` with `GL_TRIANGLES` may be useful ? Could you provide please some example ?

Answer (score 2):

You would use them when you have multiple, discontiguous ranges of primitives to draw (without any state changes between them).

The [availability of `gl_DrawID` in vertex shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs) makes it possible to issue multiple draws in such a way that the VS can index into some memory to find the specific per-model data for that rendering call. So in that event, you could draw dozens of entirely separate models, using different transforms stored in a buffer, all with the same draw call.

So long as you can put their per-model data in a buffer object indexable by the draw identifier (and so long as all of these models use the same vertex format and buffer storage), you could render much of the entire scene in a single call.

Comment: It leads me to the following conclusion: when I don't use gl_DrawID or drawing doesn't require a "restart functionality" I don't need glMultiDrawElements/glMulitDrawArrays. Do you agree with that ?

Comment: @Irbis: You seem to be trying to formulate a set of rules that you will just follow and move on. Stop that. APIs are *tools*; use them as such. Programming is too complicated to just follow an arbitrary set of rules; you need to understand what the tools you have do and use that knowledge to solve the problems in front of you. Understand what those tools do, then decide on a case-by-case basis what you need.